# Form data not being stored in database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have an HTML form that when submitted sends the data to createUser.php. The data is then stored in variables and inserted into the database using the enterUserData function. I var_dump the $_POST array and all the data is there, however, it does not get entered into the database. I have checked for spelling errors, removed the marital status because of it being on a datalist, changed $_POST to $_REQUEST, and yet it still doesn't work. There are no 400 or 500 errors either. The connection to the database is fine. I use the same connect.php file in other parts of the program and they work fine. Any insight into this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the form.

```
<form id="createUserForm" class="" action="createUser.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return createUser.validateForm('createUserForm')">
<label for="formUsername">Username: </label>
<input id="formUsername" type="text" required name="Username" placeholder="Username">
<br />
<label for="formPassword">Password: </label>
<input id="formPassword" type="text" required name="Password" placeholder="Password">
<br />
<label for="formFirstname">Firstname: </label>
<input id="formFirstname" type="text" required name="Firstname" placeholder="Firstname">
<br />
<label for="formLastname">Lastname: </label>
<input id="formLastname" type="text" required name="Lastname" placeholder="Lastname">
<br />
<label for="formFavColor">Favorite Color: </label>
<input id="formFavColor" type="text" name="Favorite Color" placeholder="Favorite Color">
<br />
<label for="formFavMove">Favorite Movie: </label>
<input id="formFavMove" type="text" name="Favorite Movie" placeholder="Favorite Movie">
<br />
<label for="formFavAnimal">Favorite Animal: </label>
<input id="formFavAnimal" type="text" name="Favorite Animal" placeholder="Favorite Animal">
<br />
<label for="formFaveVideogame">Favorite Videogame:</label>
<input id="formFaveVideogame" type="text" name="Favorite Videogame" placeholder="Favorite Videogame">
<br />
<label for="formMarital">Marital Status: </label>
<input list="formMarital" name="Marital Status">
<datalist id="formMarital" type="text" name="" placeholder="Marital Status">
<option value="Single"></option>
<option value="Married"></option>
<option value="None of my business"></option>
</datalist>
<br />
<button id="submitCreateUser" type="submit" name="button">Create User</button>
</form>
```

Here is the createUser.php file.

```
include 'loginManager.php';

function enterUserData($Username,$Password,$Firstname,$Lastname,$DateJoined,$FavoriteColor,$FavoriteMovie,$FavoriteAnimal,$FavoriteVideogame,$MaritalStatus){
  include 'connect.php';
  $query = $loginSystem->prepare("INSERT INTO users (Username,Password,FirstName,LastName,DateJoined,FavoriteColor,FavoriteMovie,FavoriteAnimal,FavoriteVideogame,MaritalStatus) VALUES ($Username,$Password,$Firstname,$Lastname,$DateJoined,$FavoriteColor,$FavoriteMovie,$FavoriteAnimal,$FavoriteVideogame,$MaritalStatus)");
  $query->execute();
}

$username = $_POST["Username"];
$password = $_POST["Password"];
$firstname = $_POST["Firstname"];
$lastname = $_POST["Lastname"];
$dateJoined = strftime('%D');
$favoriteColor = $_POST["Favorite Color"];
$favoriteMovie = $_POST["Favorite Movie"];
$favoriteAnimal = $_POST["Favorite Animal"];
$favoriteVideogame = $_POST["Favorite Videogame"];
$maritalStatus = $_POST["Marital Status"];

enterUserData($username,$password,$firstname,$lastname,$dateJoined,$favoriteColor,$favoriteMovie,$favoriteAnimal,$favoriteVideogame,$maritalStatus);
```

Here is the connect.php file.

```
$host       = "localhost";
$username   = "root";
$password   = "";
$dbname     = "login_system";

$dsn ="mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname;";

$loginSystem = new PDO($dsn,$username,$password);
```

Comment: Put error_reporting (E_ALL); on top of createUser.php to display all errors.

Comment: Have you checked if empty row was inserted into database?

Comment: See about prepared and bound queries

Comment: Show us JS code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out the problem. The name of a few of the text fields had a space between words. When collected in $_POST, PHP will replace the space with an underscore. On lines 16-20 I had used a space, since that's how the name is spelled in HTML, instead of an underscore. As others pointed out, I forgot to put '' around the variable names in the prepared statement. Thank you to everyone who helped!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `'`. Here's your new `enterUserData` function:

```
function enterUserData($Username,$Password,$Firstname,$Lastname,$DateJoined,$FavoriteColor,$FavoriteMovie,$FavoriteAnimal,$FavoriteVideogame,$MaritalStatus){
  include 'connect.php';
  $query = $loginSystem->prepare("INSERT INTO users (Username,Password,FirstName,LastName,DateJoined,FavoriteColor,FavoriteMovie,FavoriteAnimal,FavoriteVideogame,MaritalStatus) VALUES ('$Username','$Password','$Firstname','$Lastname','$DateJoined','$FavoriteColor','$FavoriteMovie','$FavoriteAnimal','$FavoriteVideogame','$MaritalStatus')");
  $query->execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please try to the below code once:-

```
$dateJoined = strftime('%D'); to $dateJoined = date('Y-m-d');
```

And replace this line:-

```
  $query = $loginSystem->prepare("INSERT INTO users (Username,Password,FirstName,LastName,DateJoined,FavoriteColor,FavoriteMovie,FavoriteAnimal,FavoriteVideogame,MaritalStatus) VALUES ('$Username','$Password','$Firstname','$Lastname','$DateJoined','$FavoriteColor','$FavoriteMovie','$FavoriteAnimal','$FavoriteVideogame','$MaritalStatus')");
```

May the date format has thrown error while saving the data.

Answer (score 0):

I think the prepared statement should look more like this:

```
$query = $loginSystem->prepare("INSERT INTO users (Username,Password,FirstName,LastName,DateJoined,FavoriteColor,FavoriteMovie,FavoriteAnimal,FavoriteVideogame,MaritalStatus) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

$query->bind_param("ssssssssss", $Username,$Password,$Firstname,$Lastname,$DateJoined,$FavoriteColor,$FavoriteMovie,$FavoriteAnimal,$FavoriteVideogame,$MaritalStatus);

$query->execute();
```

[PHP PDO prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/de/pdo.prepared-statements.php)